# Issue with PHP Session

Tags: php, session

I am building a PHP application that uses sessions to manage users login state. I am having an issue though. I start a session and a few `$_SESSION` variables upon login. The user is then redirected to his/her dashboard. The code displays the users' information properly based on the session variables, but if the link to visit his/her profile is clicked, it appears the session ends. On each page I call `session_start()` and then check if the email session variable is set. The latter always returns false after I navigate away from the dashboard. I tried to return to the dashboard to see if it was just an issue with the profile page, but the dashboard check for the email being set returns false as well. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you checking the email session in your code, and how are you setting it? That is likely the crux of the matter.

Comment: this is somewhat off topic, but have you considered using a PHP framework that would make this low level boostrap approach un-needed? Check out http://codeigniter.com and just make your app, not boilerplate stuff.

Comment: show the code you are using for checking sessions

Comment: there's not much that can be advised without the code.

Comment: show the code. it looks like you are trying to build an entire login system from scratch without knowing the basics. don't do this ! it will give you a lot of stress and time killing issues

Comment: After I check that the entered password matches the stored password for a given email: $_SESSION['email'] = $entered_email; And then for the check I do if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { do work }

Comment: are you sure that `session_destroy()` code execution is not there part of dashboard page? Code snippets helps a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: @sundar I have a link on the dashboard where I unset all of my session variables, but that shouldn't be effecting it since it just a link and the unset code resides in another script.

Comment: I had an interesting idea so I changed the redirect upon successful login to the profile page and it would display information correctly. I then tried to navigate from the profile page to the dashboard and the session data did not get destroyed. Went back to the profile page and it still worked. So I am very confused as to what is going on

Comment: Switched it back to redirect to dashboard and it worked as it should..very strange bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with `register_globals` being set to on before.

Also try printing out the `$_SESSION` variable

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Well I threw that in a test script, and it printed out the 4 session variables I set in my application, as well as the test variable set in the same script. I also placed it into the profile page script and it returned array(0).

Comment: So for some reason it appears that whenever I navigate from the dashboard, the session variables get cleared..no clue why

Comment: Checked my settings and register_globals are off. Any other suggestions?

Comment: as sundar said on your question post make sure that  session_destroy() isn't being used in your code apart from the logout function.

Comment: I went through every line of code and the only place I destroy/unset my session data is in the sign out script. As I said above it was working for awhile, but now the error appears to be happening again